# Variation on St. Petersburg Paradox, with total loss at the end

Tags: probability, expected-value, paradox, game-theory

I’m not too sure how to answer these variations I thought of and was hoping someone could enlighten me.

A casino offers a game of chance for a single player in which a fair coin is tossed at each stage. A fair coin is flipped until it comes up tails the first time, or when the player decides to stop. At that point the player stops, and the player wins $2^n$ dollars, where n is the number of times the coin was flipped. The first time tails appear however, the game ends and the player gets nothing. What is the optimal number of flips the player should go for? And what is the expected value of this game? (E.g. if a player goes for 6 flips, gets 6 heads in a row and ends the game, he receives $2^6$ dollars, but if the player goes for 6 flips and on flip number 6 a tail shows up, he receives zero dollars)

Also, what if the game changes such that instead of doubling, the total amount accumulated increases by 1 dollar each time a head appears?

Comment: Do you mean that the gambler is wagering $2 of their own money, so if they stop after the first flip then on heads they win 2 and on tails they lose 2? Or, do you mean if it's tails they win 0, but haven't lost any of their own money?

Comment: Sorry for the poor wording. I meant the latter, i.e. if it's tails they win 0, but haven't lost any of their own money. Thank you for responding David.

Comment: I think this version is much clearer, but different than what I originally thought. Hint: Consider the situation after the gambler has won n flips in a row and is sitting at W potential winnings. Show that for the first version the expected winnings after flipping one more time is still W. For the second version the expected winnings after flipping one more time is 0.5W + 0.5.